# Python: Initialize variable in expression of if condition

Tags: python

In the following code, i am computing nums.index() twice.

```
if ((elem in nums) and i != nums.index(elem)):
     j = nums.index(elem)
     return i,j
```

Is there a way through which I can initialize the variable in the expression itself and use it in the scope of the if condition? Maybe something like this

```
if ((elem in nums) and i != (j = nums.index(elem))):
   return i,j
```

Comment: Short answer: Use `j := nums.index(...)` instead of `j = nums.index(...)` for Python >= 3.8. For earlier Python versions initialise `j` before the `if` line (which, in my opinion, is more readable anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that using `The Walrus Operator :=`

```
elem = 10
nums = [11, 2, 10, 2, 3]


def fun():
    i = 3
    if (elem in nums) and i != (j := nums.index(elem)):
        return i, j


fun()
```